# (Unity AWS SDK) failled to get Google cloud messaging registration id

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I am using the amazon aws sdk for unity and trying to get the push notifications to work, so after setting the project up at google developers console and enabling
GCM when I try to run the app it says failed to get the GCM registration ID, after looking up at other similar questions on here I made sure my manifest is set right.

Here's the Manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.amazonaws.unity"
  android:installLocation="preferExternal"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

  <supports-screens
  android:smallScreens="true"
  android:normalScreens="true"
  android:largeScreens="true"
  android:xlargeScreens="true"
  android:anyDensity="true"/>

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />


  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"      />

  <permission android:name="com.amazonaws.unity.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
  android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.amazonaws.unity.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


  <application
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
  android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:debuggable="true">

  <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true"  />
  <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik"  android:value="false" />
  </activity>

    <receiver
     android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
     android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
    <category android:name="com.amazonaws.unity" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

  <service android:name="com.amazonaws.unity.GCMIntentService" />
  </application>
  </manifest>
```

the part of the code which retrieves the Registration ID:

```
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(GoogleConsoleProjectId))
        {
            Debug.Log("sender id is null");
            debug.text = "sender id is null";
            return;
        }
        GCM.Register((regId) =>
        {

            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(regId))
            {
                ResultText.text = string.Format("Failed to get the registration id");
                    debug.text = "Failed to get the registration id";

                return;
            }

            ResultText.text = string.Format(@"Your registration Id is = {0}", regId);

            SnsClient.CreatePlatformEndpointAsync(
                new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest
                {
                    Token = regId,
                    PlatformApplicationArn = AndroidPlatformApplicationArn
                },
                (resultObject) =>
                {
                    if(resultObject.Exception==null)
                    {
                        CreatePlatformEndpointResponse response = resultObject.Response;
                        _endpointArn = response.EndpointArn;
                        ResultText.text += string.Format(@"Platform endpoint arn is = {0}", response.EndpointArn);
                    }
                }
            );
        }, GoogleConsoleProjectId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Before implementing the steps given in [Configuring the Unity Sample App for Android](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforunity/developerguide/sns.html), please ensure that you have the following **Android Prerequisites** as given in [Amazon Simple Notification Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforunity/developerguide/sns.html):

- Install the Android SDK
- Install the JDK
- android-support-v4.jar
- google-play-services.jar

Please also note the concept given in [Unity Sample (Android)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforunity/developerguide/sns.html#unity-sample-android),

> The app displays two buttons labeled **Register for Notification** and **Unregister**. When the **Register for Notifications** button is tapped, the `RegisterDevice()` method is called. `RegisterDevice()` calls `GCM.Register`, which registers the app with GCM. It makes an asynchronous call to register the app with GCM.

In addition to given AWS documentations, you may also check this AWS Discussion Forum regarding [Unity SNS example](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=212072).

Comment: thank you for redirecting me to that thread, i've posted my question there as well.

And yes I have all 4 of these in my project , and about the google-play-services. jar since the latest revision 30, google decided to separate the google play services library into smaller ones so I am using an older one (29). also I did follow all the the steps mention in the guide and I am using the demo SNS scene which aws provides